# sap.m.Table: How to scroll to given listItem

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using a sap.m.Table to display my entries. The user has the possibility to delete list items and in that case I would like to scroll to the list item which was below or above the deleted one once, the binding is updated. I do get the position of the deleted list item by calling indexOfItem but how to scroll to that position I don't know.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

answer of your question should be

```
oList.getItems()[index].getDomRef().scrollIntoView().
```

but not to loose the keyboard navigation you can call

```
oList.getItems()[index].focus();
```

then browser will scroll to the item as well since m lib uses native scrolling. focus method is public for every control.

Since 1.26 you can just call oList.focus(); list remembers the last focused item for you.

something like this should work in a  delete handler.

```
oList.attachEventOnce("updateFinished", oList.focus.bind(oList));
deleteSelectedRecordFromModel();
```